# C# AutoMapper, filtering out values during mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a question about AutoMapper that I am struggling to solve

Consider a scenario where we are doing a mapping between a Business type to an API type:

```
public class BusinessType
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
  public bool Visible { get; set; }
}

public class ApiType
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Creating a map for this is straightforward. Assuming that we want to explicitly map each property:

```
cfg.CreateMap<BusinessType, ApiType>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.ID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ID))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value));
```

However, the complication for me is how to do this where we filter out any records for the API type where the business type has visible = 0.

For example, if five BusinessType values are contained in a list, and three of those values had visible = 1 and two had visible = 0, I would want the resulting list of ApiTypes to only contain three records, which would be those from the original list that had visible = 1.

Does anyone know how I might achieve that?

Many thanks and best regards

Comment: How are you performing the mapping itself?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it, with some experimentation:

```
cfg.CreateMap<List<BusinessType>, List<ApiType>>()
  .ConvertUsing((src, dest) => dest = ConvertAndFilter(src));

private List<ApiType> ConvertAndFilter(List<BusinessType>)
{
  // do code in here to covert the list, filtering out those with visible = 0
}
```